# Why I get "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'multi.js' " when module is installed globally?

Tags: node.js, electron, multi.js

I have installed the packacge `multi.js` as `npm install --global --verbose multi.js` and also set the `NODE_PATH` environment variable to the `export NODE_PATH=/home/wasim/.nvm/versions/node/v13.1.0/lib/node_module`. I can also view that module is indeed installed globally as,

```
npm list -g -depth 0
├── http-server@0.12.3
├── multi.js@0.5.1
├── npm@6.14.8
├── xls@0.5.1
└── xlsx@0.16.6
```

However, when I load the module as `const multi_js = require('multi.js');`, I get error:  `Cannot find module 'multi.js'` as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

What I'm missing here?
Thanks

Note: this error also occurs for local installation of multi.js package.

Comment: well this is definitely not a good practice, all your modules should by installed in a local node_modules folder, use a global modules only for globally used modules that are not listed in pachage.json, for example cli tools

Comment: I switched to global installation, only after I got this error locally. do you have any idea why this is happening? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am coding in 'non es6' js standard, so I tried `const multi = require('../libs/multi.js-master/dist/multi.min.js');` but it did not work, I got this error: `index.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: multi is not a function`

**What worked for me is loading multi.min.js in the index.html as follows:**

```
<script src="../libs/multi.js-master/dist/multi.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround  https://github.com/fabianlindfors/multi.js/issues/41 probably is the best way to import multi nowadays via npm/yarn